# I have to publish my web app to server using ssh

Tags: ssh, server

I have developed an app in nodejs/angular and now I have to publish the app to the server using the given ssh details. It's a linux server, i have experience to publishing the app or website to the server using cPanel and Filezilla.

But i don't have any idea how to transfer the code to the server using ssh from the terminal. Using Git is the one option but i am looking for another option in case project not using Git/SVN

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use SFTP/SCP. FileZilla can work with the first one. SCP is commandline tool.

Comment: By SCP you are referring to this one right ?http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know filezilla, use that. It can connect through ssh as well as ftp. Its called sftp.

Comment: oh yes. It is pretty straight forward. Thanks.